# ZMQ c++ (cppzmq) closed socket doesn't end associated thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, sockets, zeromq

I don;t know how to clean correctly a zmq socket_t created within a std::jthread when the thread is finished.

Bellow is a test case function that creates a push socket, wait little bit than disconnects and closes the socket (wait can be replaced with a send, the behavior is identical):

```
void async_func(std::stop_token& stoken, zmq::context_t* _context)
{
        std::string _zmq_ipc_push_socket_name("ipc:///tmp/p3pushpull");
        zmq::socket_t push_socket(*_context, zmq::socket_type::push);
        push_socket.connect(_zmq_ipc_push_socket_name.c_str());

        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(500));

        push_socket.disconnect(_zmq_ipc_push_socket_name.c_str());
        push_socket.close();
}
```

This function is called in a main thread:

```
#include <thread>
#include <memory>
#include "zmq.hpp"
#include "zmq_addon.hpp"

int main(int argc, char **argv) {
        zmq::context_t _context = zmq::context_t(1);
        std::shared_ptr<std::jthread> async_call_thread;

        for (size_t idx = 0; idx < 10; idx++)
        {
               // jthread creation
               async_call_thread = std::make_shared<std::jthread>([this](std::stop_token stoken){
                      if (stoken.stop_requested()) return;
                      async_func(stoken, &_context);
               });
               if (async_call_thread)
               {
                      if (async_call_thread->joinable())
                      {
                               async_call_thread->request_stop();
                               async_call_thread->join();
                      }
                
                      async_call_thread.reset();
               }
        }

        return 0;
}
```

My issue is that when I look within GDB the thread management, I see, as expected, two threads created (one for the jthread and one for the socket). However, once the thread is joined and reset, only the jthread exits. There is an accumulation of lingering threads corresponding the the sockets' creation that are only exited once the main thread ends.

This is obviously an issue as if I use 1000 threads, this could create a big issue. Even If I only create the socket (without the connection) than close it, I still have the issue.

How could I ensure that the threads corresponding to the created and closed sockets are cleaned once the jthread is done?

Answer (score 0):

zmq internal threads are associated with the current `zmq::context`, they are destroyed in the destructor of the `context` which happens at the end of your `main`, their number is limited by the number of threads you pass into the context constructor.

the max number of threads you should use will depend on the system resources, a system can generally handle network threads 2 to 4 times the number of logical cores without slowdowns, depending on the processing done.

Comment: Then, there is something I don't get. On one side you cannot share a socket between threads and on another you cannot create them dynamically because they are accumulating without being able to join them... What is the solution then?

Comment: @PMDP3 a solution to what ? zmq uses a threadpool to wait on blocking IO, the threadpool reuses those threads for all the socket that you open, they don't grow in numbers above the maximum number you set in the constructor, you don't need to join them or worry about their growth, the existence of threads is an implementation detail used to maximize the library's performance, and you do have control over the max number of threads to limit your application's resources, and zmq handles all the necessary cleanup of threads when the context is destroyed.

Comment: this is exactly my point. I have a context with a single IO thread. However, when I run the code above I see that each time a jthread is created, the socket creates also a thread that is not exited when the jthread is joined (even if the socket is closed). Those "socket's threads" are exited when the context is closed. Therefore, I do have more than the number of threads set in the context...

Comment: @PMDP3 zmq only limits the threads it creates, you are responsible for limiting the threads you create, i see no reason to use a jthread here, you could use coroutines or run the program in your main thread or use a small threadpool to speed up distribution, you don't have to create a thread for every socket.